# Flutter: "flutter pub get" gets stuck

Tags: flutter, git, github, dependencies, flutter-dependencies

**I'm trying to get packages, when I run `flutter pub get` nothing happens or it get stuck**

```
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\clone\my_app> flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in my_app...          /
```

Tried upgrading flutter.
Tried running it on multiple networks.

**when I used `flutter pug get --verbose` this was the output:**

```
    cloud_firestore","homepage":"https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/tree/master/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore_web","repository":"https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/tree/master/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore_web","version":"3.1.0","environment":{"sdk":">=2.16.0
<3.0.0","flutter":">=1.20.0"},"dependencies":{"_flutterfire_internals":"^1.0.9","cloud_firestore_platform_interface":"^5.9.0","collection":"^1.0.0","firebase_core":"^2.3.0","firebase_core_web":"^2.0.1","flutter":{"sdk":"flutter"},"flutter_web_plugins":{"sdk":"flutter"},"js":"^0.6.3"},"dev_dependencies":{"firebase_core_platform_interface":"^4.5.2","flutter_test":{"sdk":"flutter"},"mockito":"^5.0.0"},"flutter":{"plugin":{"platforms":{"web":{"pluginClass":"FirebaseFirestoreWeb","fileName":"cloud_firestore_web.dart"}}}}},"archive_url":"https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cloud_firestore_web/versions/3.1.0.tar.gz","archive_sha256":"3c9a77380e6a053129c2cb6dbe8ef1b708f4350ce0dad220d2c05cd68a2d467f","published":"2022-11-17T14:00:52.599889Z"},{"version":"3.1.1","pubspec":{"name":"cloud_firestore_web","description":"The web implementation of
cloud_firestore","homepage":"https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/tree/master/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore_web","repository":"https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/tree/master/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore_web","version":"3.1.1","environment":{"sdk":">=2.16.0
<3.0.0","flutter":">=1.20.0"},"dependencies":{"_flutterfire_internals":"^1.0.10","cloud_firestore_platform_interface":"^5.9.1","collection":"^1.0.0","firebase_core":"^2.4.0","firebase_core_web":"^2.0.2","flutter":{"sdk":"flutter"},"flutter_web_plugins":{"sdk":"flutter"},"js":"^0.6.3"},"dev_dependencies":{"firebase_core_platform_interface":"^4.5.2","flutter_test":{"sdk":"flutter"},"mockito":"^5.0.0"},"flutter":{"plugin":{"platforms":{"web":{"pluginClass":"FirebaseFirestoreWeb","fileName":"cloud_firestore_web.dart"}}}}},"archive_url":"https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cloud_firestore_web/versions/3.1.1.tar.gz","archive_sha256":"b6a5712dc5d74473249b0777b93e6adf0ae68aeabae2699238d4647f3d5e1624","published":"2022-12-08T14:07:35.355432Z"},{"version":"3.2.0","pubspec":{"name":"cloud_firestore_web","description":"The web implementation of
cloud_firestore","homepage":"https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/tree/master/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore_web","repository":"https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/tree/master/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore_web","version":"3.2.0","environment":{"sdk":">=2.16.0
<3.0.0","flutter":">=1.20.0"},"dependencies":{"_flutterfire_internals":"^1.0.11","cloud_firestore_platform_interface":"^5.10.0","collection":"^1.0.0","firebase_core":"^2.4.0","firebase_core_web":"^2.0.2","flutter":{"sdk":"flutter"},"flutter_web_plugins":{"sdk":"flutter"},"js":"^0.6.3"},"dev_dependencies":{"firebase_core_platform_interface":"^4.5.2","flutter_test":{"sdk":"flutter"},"mockito":"^5.0.0"},"flutter":{"plugin":{"platforms":{"web":{"pluginClass":"FirebaseFirestoreWeb","fileName":"cloud_firestore_web.dart"}}}}},"archive_url":"https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cloud_firestore_web/versions/3.2.0.tar.gz","archive_sha256":"2d7339bf3f79adcdb123a88e908474478b060317332189bdd5dcb2d498952127","published":"2022-12-22T12:35:55.126423Z"}],"_fetchedAt":"2022-12-28T11:16:24.333312"}
```

This is the last 6 lines I get

any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: tried running flutter doctor, and did you ensure that when you run pub get the program is closed?

Comment: @Nikhil i only have on issue when i run flutter doctor ,

 [!] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.4.3)
    X Visual Studio is missing necessary components. Please re-run the Visual Studio installer for the "Desktop
      development with C++" workload, and include these components:
        MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools
         - If there are multiple build tool versions available, install the latest
        C++ CMake tools for Windows
        Windows 10 SDK